# Is there any chat client which works behind authenticated proxy server?

Tags: system-settings

I am behind an **authenticated proxy server** and I have set it up via

**System->Preferences->Network Proxy** configuration and *applied system-wide*.

But most of the chat clients (primarily to access gtalk) do not make use of this setting or even do not work with application specific proxy settings if any. I have found no luck with Empathy, Pidgin etc.

So is there a **chat client** that **works fine behind an authenticated proxy server**?

*Equally well will be to get any idea to get a workaround for the problem with empathy etc*.

I am using Ubuntu 11.04 with Gnome-classic if that matters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alas, I could make empathy work behind the authenticated proxy by using the [cntlm](http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/).

```
 sudo apt-get install cnltm
```

and edit the

`gedit /etc/cntlm.conf`

( You need to give proxy address, username and password, and default port to listen on localhost)

After this configure gnome to use localhost:port (the value we gave in conf file), and try empathy now after starting cntlm

```
cntlm
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm having problems with that too (empathy, pidgin and emesene 2 don't work). So i use the IM+ app inside Chrome, and the official app they develop for Chrome OS that is also available for download, and works too (btw, the extention name "Chromify" that makes chrome notification compatible with Notify OSD works pefect with IM+).

So go for IM+, the official gtalk, or just the gmail chat window ;-).

IM+ supports msn, skype, icq, etc... so it's a good choice.

Comment: But it needs Chrome browser to be kept open at all times?

Comment: Yep i'm afraid so. But it's not a big deal in my humble opinion ;-)

Comment: Btw, Emesene2 got an update and i was able to login behind a proxy to MSN from there. Couldn't on gtalk so i'm using im+. You could give it a try adding this ppa:

    ppa:emesene-team/emesene-stable

Comment: authenticated proxy?

Comment: yeap. At least, Just tried at the college network with an squid proxy authenticated against a ldap